# 3V DC Motor - 9V Battery?

Tags: dc-motor

I recently bought a 3VDC 350mA (13800RPM) motor. Only problem is, I can't seem to find a way to power it. I have a 9V battery, can I use this to power it? If not what do I need to do to power it correctly?

Comment: Why not use two AA batteries in series?  (or if you need to run it for a long time, two C-cells in series?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably got something similar to one of these: -

[image]

And if you have these are probably not going to be able to supply the start current needed to get you motor moving. They have a typical DC resistance between 2 ohms and 4 ohms and these are pretty good types. Others may have an internal resistance of up to 10 ohms and, of course you may be using a partially discharged battery.

Either go for a couple of AA batteries in series (having a total series internal resistance of about 0.3 ohms) or use a buck regulator to drop the voltage (efficiently) to 3V.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your 9V battery if you step down the V to ~3V.
You can search Ebay for a DC-DC stepdown converter (usually less than 3$).

The other thing you can do is buy an AC to DC adapter that plugs into the wall & steps down the voltage from 120V AC to ~3V DC.
Once again, Ebay is useful for finding such devices.  This may not be a useful solution for you, however, if your motor application is for a portable gadget like a RC machine.

HTH

Best regards!